# parse json string into a javascript objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I'm using Firefox 19.0.2.
I receive a JSON string (into a JavaScript function) with changing sizes,

sometimes it is:

```
var jsonstring = {"CA":"CA","NY":"NY","TX":"TX"}
```

sometimes it is:

```
var jsonstring = {"Hello":"Hello","Goodbye":"Goodbye"}
```

I want to create a result array like this (in case of the first example):

```
data[0].value = "CA"
data[0].text = "CA"

data[1].value = "NY"
data[1].text = "NY"

data[2].value = "TX"
data[2].text = "TX"
```

How do I do that?

I read tens of early posts here and tried a couple of `for` loops, but nothing works.

Comment: Just to be pedantic: those are not "JSON strings", those are JavaScript objects declared with object literal syntax.

Comment: @Pointy That's not pedantic, that's a very important distinction.

Comment: Could this be the reason that when i loop on jsonstring with indexes: jsonstring[0], jsonstring[1]... i get letters instead of strings? jsonstring[0] = "{" ,jsonstring[1] = """,jsonstring[2] = "C"..... ?

Comment: @Pointy can you please explain? i don't know what you mean...

Comment: @Rodniko well a JSON **string** is a string value that contains (unparsed) JSON. What you posted are JavaScript object literal expressions.  They *look like* JSON because JSON is a simplified form of JavaScript object literal syntax, but they don't need parsing because the JavaScript interpreter already parsed them.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `JSON.parse` to convert to an object (In your example you arleady have an object though):

```
var obj= JSON.parse('{"CA":"CA","NY":"NY","TX":"TX"}')
```

Keep in mind, you can't depend on the order of the attributes in an object, so you could not accomplish what you are trying to do above in a for loop.

Comment: Thank you Justin, but what do i do afterwards? i tried a loop but there is no obj[0]. i also tried obj[0].key but it doesn't work. how do i read the content of obj in a loop after the parsing?

Comment: Try pasting the above code into your browsers console, chrome has a good one.  Then play around with the object, example: obj.CA == 'CA'

Answer (score 0):

The transform after using `JSON.parse` to get an object from the JSON, would look something like that:

```
obj = {
  CA: 'CA',
  LA: 'LA'
};

arr = [];

for (var key in obj) {
  if(!obj.hasOwnProperty(key))
    continue;
  arr.push({value: key, text: obj[key]});
}
// Output
[{ value: "CA", text: "CA" }, { value: "LA", text: "LA" }]
```